# JSONObject not null but appears be null

Tags: java, null, arrays, java-server, json

I'm having a heck of problem with Java's JSONObject

so I had a bug, there found the issue with following test code:

```
    assertTrue(message.toJSON() != null);
    assertTrue(JSONFactory.toJSON(message) != null);
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.put(message.toJSON());
    jsonArray.put(JSONFactory.toJSON(message));
    try {
        assertTrue(jsonArray.get(0) != null);
        assertTrue(jsonArray.get(1) != null);
        DebugLog.d(jsonArray.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }
```

everything passes, but the toString() gives [null, null], so when I send the array to fontend, it receives [null, null] (not good)

I did some research and it appears to have something to do with JSONOBject.null, but I have no idea why it would happen

and my toJSON() method is like:

```
    JSONObject jsonMessage = new JSONObject();
    try{
            //**adding a bunch of stuff
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonMessage;
```

Comment: Its good story but how can we help you? please post `message`

Comment: Well I didn't think how Message class would affect the outcome, because even if I empty the try clause it is still null